# Unable to tunnel through proxy - Jsoup

Tags: java, proxy, jsoup, tunneling

I am getting the below exception while creating an HTTP connection.

```
2017-08-07 17:07:43,219 ERROR au.com.scraper.sites.ScraperSite - Exception in parsing Categories: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" at line number 153
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2085)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:563)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:183)
    at au.com.scraper.sites.ScraperSite.getCategories(ScraperSite.java:127)
    at au.com.scraper.sites.AScraperSites.execute(AScraperSites.java:74)
    at au.com.scraper.Scraper.main(Scraper.java:88)
```

Below is my proxy configuration.

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("user_name", "password"));
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", server);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port);
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", server);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port);
```

Below is my Proxy Authenticator class.

```
package au.com.scraper;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
public class ProxyAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{
    public ProxyAuthenticator(String user, String password)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
    }
    private String user;
    private String password;
}
```

Can any one suggest why this issue is happening?

Comment: have you tried disabling disabledSchemes? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41806109/6503002

Comment: Could you please also post the code of your `ProxyAuthenticator` class.

Comment: @SubOptimal ... I have updated the ProxyAuthenticator class.

Comment: Code is correct. The username and/or password are incorrect. Or maybe JSoup replaces your `Authenticator`, which would mean it has some other API you need to use.

Comment: @EJP   Thanks for your comments. the code is correct. If the user name/ password is updated, the JVM needs to be restarted. I have restarted my machine and surprisingly it worked.

Comment: The JVM doesn't *have* to be restarted: the application needs to be told about it, and needs to install a new `Authenticator`.

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy server might be blocking that web address, we might face this issue when the web address is local address and your proxy server will be blocking that.