# Gradle : Unable to tunnel through proxy

Tags: gradle, flutter, http-proxy, http-status-code-407

I am trying to run a blank Flutter project behind a corporate proxy requiring basic authentication and self-signing HTTPS connections.

I added the necessary config in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and in `~/.profile`. I also imported my root certificate in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` and told Gradle to use it. I even tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43238418/5083247) and set `java.net.useSystemProxies=true` in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/net.properties`.

But, still, it doesn't build, and it asks for authentication.

```
flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on Nexus 5 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                0.8s
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: ~/GitLab/n.gendron/techno_store/android/gradlew app:properties:
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
Failed to download any source lists!
```

[This guide](https://serviceorientedarchitect.com/using-gradle-wrapper-behind-a-proxy-server-with-self-signed-ssl-certificates/) helped me a lot trough this process, and [this one](http://blog.mindcrime-ilab.de/2015/05/20/dev-notesgradle-use-gradle-wrapper-with-self-signed-organization-local-certificates/) helped me import the CA, but now I'm stuck.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: No, the problem wasn't solved. We temporary made a hole in our security systems just to allow Flutter to download itself. I really wish Java respected the system's configuration to access Internet and didn't try to be a smart-ass about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need in gradle/gradle.properties write:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
...

systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=443
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=443
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=domain

...
```