# Finding the JRE used by JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I have jmeter 5.2.1. I have created a Blaze meter recording. But while running the test, I get error -Unable to tunnel through proxy.
I have Java 32 and 64 bits installed on my pc.
I am trying to implement the information I got from

[Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns “HTTP/1.1 407” via https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505219/unable-to-tunnel-through-proxy-proxy-returns-http-1-1-407-via-https)

How can I find which JRE is used by the jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead editing global Java `net.properties` file I would rather recommend making the changes in JMeter's [system.properties file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
2. On Windows you should be able to get the `java` executable path using [wmic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290216/a-description-of-the-windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-command-li) utility like:

   ```
   wmic process where name='java.exe' get commandline
   ```

   on Unix and derivatives you can use [`ps` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) to determine it like:

   ```
   ps -ef | grep java
   ```
3. And last but not the least you can always query this information from [Java System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)  like:

   ```
   log.info('Java installation: ' + System.getProperty('java.home'))
   log.info('Java name: ' + System.getProperty('java.vm.name'))
   log.info('Java bits: ' + System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model'))
   ```

   [image]